# kotlin-kapt plugin with version catalogs

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose, annotation-processing

I have migrated my build to use version catalogs.
I have removed the following from my build.gradle

```
plugins {
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

and

```
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
```

now I am getting

```
warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: 
'[dagger.hilt.internal.useAggregatingRootProcessor, room.schemaLocation, 
dagger.fastInit, dagger.hilt.android.internal.disableAndroidSuperclassValidation, 
dagger.hilt.android.internal.projectType]'
```

1 warning

and

```
A failure occurred while executing 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
 > 2 files found with path 'META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors' from 
 inputs:
  - /.gradle/caches/transforms- 
 3/5f588ae3973231906376832b3350f55d/transformed/jetified-hilt-android-compiler- 
 2.45.jar
   - /.gradle/caches/transforms- 
 3/f1c91d9e7fbd546100043f736678c477/transformed/jetified-dagger-compiler-2.45.jar
```

Now I am wondering how to add `kotlin-kapt` as a plugin to the version catalogs.
Or how do I use the `annotationProcessor` with version catalogs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**libs.version.toml**

```
[versions]
com-android-application = "8.1.0-alpha11"
org-jetbrains-kotlin-android = "1.8.0"
navigation-fragment-ktx = "2.5.3"
navigation-ui-ktx = "2.5.3"

[libraries]
navigation-fragment-ktx = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-fragment-ktx", version.ref = "navigation-fragment-ktx" }
navigation-ui-ktx = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-ui-ktx", version.ref = "navigation-ui-ktx" }

[plugins]
com-android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "com-android-application" }
org-jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "org-jetbrains-kotlin-android" }
org-jetbrains-kotlin-kapt = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt", version.ref = "org-jetbrains-kotlin-android" }
```

**build.gradle(:project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.com.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt) apply false
}
```

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.com.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.jetpack"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.jetpack"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding =true
    }
}

dependencies {
    ....
    implementation(libs.navigation.fragment.ktx)
    implementation(libs.navigation.ui.ktx)
   ...
}
```

*For more detail visit this website:*

https://www.droidcon.com/2022/05/13/gradle-version-catalogs-for-an-awesome-dependency-management/

Answer (score 2):

As stated on the Android developers' website ([Link](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs)), the latest way to add and maintain dependencies in Android projects is to use the "Gradle Version Catalogs". Version Catalogs especially help with managing dependency and plugin versions across different modules in a multi-module project.

Regarding the `kapt` plugin (Kotlin annotation processor), there are two approaches that we can take when using version catalogs. Both of these approaches are correct, pick one that suits your project:

### First Approach (Fast and Simple):

Ignore the Version catalogs and the **"libs.versions.toml"** file and directly add the plugin to your module-level **build.gradle/build.gradle.kts** file (not the project level) as displayed in the example below and you are good to go.

**Module-level build.gradle.kts/build.gradle file:**

```
plugins {
    ...
    // build.gradle.kts (Kotlin)
    kotlin("kapt")

    // build.gradle (Groovy)
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
android {
    ...
}
```

Why not add it to the project-level **build.gradle.kts/build.gradle** file?! Because in this approach the plugin will use the `embeddedKotlinVersion` from **org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KoltinDependencyExtensions.kt** file, which ensures better compatibility with other Kotlin gradle plugins. Thus, there is no need to define this plugin in the project-level build.gradle.kts file as we are not explicitly defining its version.

### Second Approach (More explicit):

Unlike the previous approach, this time we will define the plugin in the **libs.versions.toml** file along with its exact version. Then we will introduce it to Project-level and Modul-level **build.gradle/build.gradle.kts** files as displayed in the example below:

**libs.versions.toml :**

```
[versions]
org-jetbrains-kotlin-android = "1.9.0"
...

[libraries]
...

[plugins]
org-jetbrains-kotlin-kapt = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt", version.ref = "org-jetbrains-kotlin-android" }
...
```

**Project-level build.gradle.kts/build.gradle file:**

```
plugins {
    ...
    //build.gradle.kts (Kotlin) 
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt) apply false 

    // build.gradle (Groovy):
    alias libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt apply false 
}
```

**Module-level build.gradle.kts/build.gradle file:**

```
plugins {
    ...
    // build.gradle.kts (Kotlin):
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt)

    // build.gradle (Groovy):
    alias libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt
}
android {
    ...
}
```

**Note:**
By the way, it is worth mentioning that Android Developers' website recommends migrating gradually from `kapt` to `KSP` which is a new alternative to kapt ([Link](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp)).

Comment: For Jetpack Room, theres already a KSP integration, but not for dagger hilt. Or is there one? Haven't found anything.

Comment: @Carsten You can check supported libraries [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-overview.html#supported-libraries).

Answer (score 0):

First, change the plugins in build.gradle(:app) like:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
```

Then implement the libraries in libs.version.toml file like shown below:

```
[versions]
daggerHilt = "2.45"
room = "2.5.1"

[libraries]
#Room
androidx-room-runtime = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-runtime", version.ref = "room" }
androidx-room-compiler = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-compiler", version.ref = "room" }
androidx-room-ktx = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-ktx", version.ref = "room" }

#Dagger - Hilt
hilt-android = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android", version.ref = "daggerHilt" }
hilt-android-compiler = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "daggerHilt" }
hilt-compiler = { group = "androidx.hilt", name = "hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltNavigation" }
hilt-navigation-compose = { group = "androidx.hilt", name = "hilt-navigation-compose", version.ref = "hiltNavigation" }

[plugins]
hilt = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "daggerHilt"}
```

Last, import the libraries in build.module(:app), you can use `kapt` or `annotationProcessor`:

```
// Dagger - Hilt
implementation(libs.hilt.android)
kapt(libs.hilt.android.compiler)
kapt(libs.hilt.compiler)
implementation(libs.hilt.navigation.compose)

// Room
implementation(libs.androidx.room.runtime)
annotationProcessor(libs.androidx.room.compiler)
kapt(libs.androidx.room.compiler)
implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)
```

And do not forget to add this in build.gradle(project), if you didn't already:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.45' apply false
}
```

Comment: In the project build.gradle what does the `apply false` do?

Answer (score 0):

```
[versions]
kotlinPlugin = "1.8.10"

[plugins]
kotlin-kapt = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt", version.ref = "kotlinPlugin" }

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.kapt) apply false
}
```

Comment: yes this worked fine for me but do you have any idea that why only kapt didn't work ?
i have used kapt first then it didn't worked but when I used kotlin-kept this did worked. i have just changed name of plugin in plugins section